# Create and actively use Process without freezing main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, backgroundworker

I'm currently trying to create new NodeJS process and while it's running, put it's console output into my winform textbox.

Whenever this process is executed, it's freezing main thread as if form is waiting for this process to exit. After the process is closed thats when the console output is added to the textbox.

What I'm trying to achieve is simultaneously have this node process running in the background and have whatever it's outputing in the textbox.

## Edit 1:

I Managed to run the console without freezing main thread but the output only shows when the process is closed

My current code:

```cs
    private void Btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            nodeProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "node.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"path" + " arg1 arg2 arg3";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            nodeProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;

            nodeProcess.Start();

            while (worker.CancellationPending != true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                AddText(nodeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                worker.ReportProgress(1);
            }

            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        public void AddText(string text)
        {
            if(txt_log.InvokeRequired)
            {
                txt_log.Invoke(new Action<string>(AddText), new object[] { text });
                return;
            }

            txt_log.Text += "\n " + text;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `BackgroundWorker` you could try using [`Process.BeginOutputReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline), [`Process.OutputDataReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived), and [`Process.Exited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited).

```csharp
void StartProcess()
{
    Process nodeProcess = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "node.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = @"path" + " arg1 arg2 arg3";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    nodeProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;

    nodeProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    nodeProcess.Exited += nodeProcess_Exited;
    nodeProcess.OutputDataReceived += nodeProcess_OutputDataReceived;

    nodeProcess.Start();
    nodeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

void nodeProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something when the process exits, if you need to.
    // You'll want to check InvokeRequired before you modify any of your form's controls.
}

void nodeProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_log.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txt_log.Invoke(new Action<string>(AddText), new object[] { e.Data });
        return;
    }
    txt_log.Text += "\n " + e.Data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, works like a charm, must have eye-balled the docs.